# Problems with permissions on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, localhost, file-permissions

I'm having problems with permissions on localhost. I'm migrating a Magento site.

When trying to go to my site with when I have **.htaccess** in root I get **Internal Server Error**.

When I rename **.htaccess** to **.htaccess.dis** I end up at the install page (index.php/install/).

So my thinking is that **.htaccess** is doing something funky...

I'm using MAMP PRO for localhost.

ps. When using normal MAMP the .htaccess doesn't give **Internal Server Error**.

```
##### Block unwanted Bots that clog the server #####

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 80legs [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]

##### Add support for SVG Graphics and CSS3 Pie #####

    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip svgz
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    DirectoryIndex index.php

##### Domain-specific PHP Settings #####

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 6768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>


##### mod_deflate compresses your output to lower the file size being sent to the client #####

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    php_flag zlib.output_compression on
</IfModule>

<Files *.php>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>


##### Header Directives #####

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>


##### disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload #####

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


##### Enable apache served files compression #####

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>


##### Mod gzip and caching for improved site speed #####

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


##### Default expires headers for all file types  #####
##### Not recommended for development environment #####

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>


##### Mime Type Caching #####

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    ##### AUDIO #####
    AddType audio/mp4 m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg oga ogg

    ##### JAVASCRIPT #####
    # Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways):
    # http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    AddType application/javascript                      js jsonp
    AddType application/json                            json

    ##### VIDEO #####
    AddType video/mp4                                   mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

    ##### WEB FONTS #####
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    ##### Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types   #####
    ##### and sniff the content, however, Chrome shows  #####
    ##### a warning if other MIME types are used for    #####
    ##### the following fonts.                          #####
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf


    ##### OTHER #####
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash               swf
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType image/x-icon                                ico
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc
    AddType text/x-vcard                                vcf

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .webapp .xml
</IfModule>


##### Disable ETags http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags #####

    FileETag None

##### Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides #####

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################



## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#    RewriteBase /sv/

############################################

## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]


## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/



############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>

    # ALLOW USER BY IP
```

Comment: If you have an 500 Server internal error, i would recommend to you to check  the logs from your server (nginx or apache) in order to get more details about what is happening

Comment: Thanks! By removing "php_flag zlib.output_compression on" it worked!